# Python fetch data from website

Tags: python-2.7

Below python code not working to fetch the data from given link. Please help me how to make it possible

```
 import urllib2
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  quote_page = 'http://www.smartvidya.co.in/2016/11/ugc-net-paper-1-previous-year-questions_14.html'
 page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
name_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'MsoNormal'})

print name_box
```

Comment: You are missing the content reading. On line 5 do:

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), 'html.parser')

Comment: @patito it is still not working. Does this code working on your side? Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean code not working ? What is the error? It's working for me.

Comment: @AlexDotis code is working but it is not working as i expected to fetch all data.

Comment: I believe I understand what you want. Instead of using the find function, you need to use the find_all function so you can iterate over the desired results. Please note that this question is too specific for your case and has to be moderated as such

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
quote_page = 'http://www.smartvidya.co.in/2016/11/ugc-net-paper-1-previous-year-questions_14.html'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
for name_box in soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class': 'MsoNormal'}):
    print name_box.text
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm glad i helped you!!